# SparkR-avg(df$column) not returning a value but just the text "Column avg"

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

This is my code

```
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS' = 
    '"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0" "sparkr-shell"')

library(SparkR)

sc=sparkR.init(master="local",
    sparkHome = "/Users/devesh/Downloads/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6",
    sparkPackages = c("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0"))

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris)
avg(df$Sepal_Length)
```

And gives me the output:

```
Column avg(Sepal_Length)
```

But not a number. I am using Mac OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an expected behavior. Same as other operators in `Sparkr` avg` is lazily evaluated. To get the value you have trigger an action. Moreover it is just at column expression and won't work alone without proper context:

```
library(magrittr)

select(df, avg(df$Sepal_Length)) %>% collect()
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion- I am getting the below output     Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  avg(df$Sepal_Length)

Comment: You clearly have some mess in your workspace :) This is `dplyr` error not SparkR.